# Как скопировать строку в зависимости от длины массива?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка "какой то текст", и в зависимости от длины массива `arr` я хочу скопировать эту строку в столько же раз. К примеру:

```
var str = "<span>some text</span>";
var arr = [{name:'John'}, {name:'Bill'},{name:'Clara'}]; // length = 3;
```

чтобы строка `str` стала `var str = "<span>some text</span><span>some text</span><span>some text</span>";`. Подскажите как это лучше сделать? Есть описания для копирования обьектов и т.д., но вот для строк не смог найти..

UPD: работа с DOM не нужна, то есть нужно либо чтобы `str` стала "больше" в зависимости от длины массива, либо создать новую переменную. В DOM это идти не будет..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = "<span>some text</span>".repeat([{name:'John'}, {name:'Bill'},{name:'Clara'}].length);
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: спасибо! str.repeat(arr.length) - помогло!